# Pivot Issue ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am running the below query and need to output the rows as columns. When I am adding the second MAX statement, I am getting an error ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT * from ( 
SELECT a.REF_NUM as "Number", a.SUMMARY, a.DESC_SEARCH as "Description", a.Status, e.Label, e.Value
        FROM ca a,
        cr_prp e
    WHERE 
        a.PERSID = e.OWNING_CR
        AND a.CATEGORY = '16996807'
        ORDER by a.REF_NUM DESC)t
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Plan/UnPlanned' THEN Value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Reason for' THEN Value END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Name & "ID"' THEN Value END)
    FOR LABEL
    IN ('Plan/UnPlanned',
        'Reason for',
        'Name & "ID"')
    )
```

Comment: I believe it is because you have three `VALUE` columns. Try placing an alias on each `MAX(...)` line to differentiate them.

Comment: You do jot need `case` expressions as `pivot` do them for you

Comment: I added an alias, however I am now seeing blank columns                                
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Plan/UnPlanned' THEN Value END) as A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Reason for' THEN Value END) as B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LABEL = 'Name & "ID"' THEN Value END) as C

Comment: How do I run this without using case if I am using Pivot.

Comment: `pivot` is equivalent for conditional aggregation: `pivot( agg(measure) for col in (val1, ..., valN))` is the same as `agg(case col when val1 then measure end), ... agg(case col when valN then measure end)` or more Oracle-stylish `agg(decode(col, val1, measure)), ...` (which is also more handy for nulls)

Comment: you see blank columns, since ELSE cases are missing for the conditionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* need something like this

```
select * from tab
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(Value)
    FOR LABEL
    IN ('Plan/UnPlanned' as PU,
        'Reason for' as R,
        'Name & "ID"' as NI)
 )  


    Number    SUMMARY D     STATUS         PU          R         NI
---------- ---------- - ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2 z          2                                1
         1          1 x          1          2                      
         2          2 y          2                     1
```

I.e. 1) add alias to you `pivot` labels

2. do not multiplicate the `MAX` calculation, it it the responsibility of `PIVOT` to calculate `max` *for each* label.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked great.